# "Specified Script not found" Eclipse PHP Xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, command-line-interface, xdebug

I am getting this error "Specified script not found" when I click debug => run as php script on my php file in Eclipse. It was working fine just this morning, and I have checked the forums and found no answer to this question. I don't see what this error could be.

update: I now don't have this error, but nevertheless, the debugger won't stop on the breakpoints. So it is still very much an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse later versions do not search /etc/php5/cli/config.d directory for additional ini files.

The solution is to compile these ini files all together.

```
cp /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php_eclipse.ini
cat /etc/php5/cli/config.d/* >> /etc/php5/cli/php_eclipse.ini
```

Then use this for the php.ini file in the eclipse php debugger settings.

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Mysterious Eclipse behavior with php xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542104/mysterious-eclipse-behavior-with-php-xdebug/13576640#13576640)

It is a solution to a problem with the same error message.