# Mysterious Eclipse behavior with php xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

Yesterday, I had some xdebug problems which people on this site very graciously helped me through.  Everything was working just fine, when suddenly, it stopped working for no disernable reason.

What I have is Eclipse running a Zend PHP debugger.  I am working my way through David Powers' book: *PHP Solutions* and using his online code, so I am doing nothing exotic.  When I try to run my PHP Webpage, I get a message saying: "Debugger Error" "Specified script cannot be found".  This tells me that the debugger can't find the PHP.exe program (right?).  Knowing that, I go to the Run Configurations dialog box and I notice that the PHP Executable form box has changed from XDebug Defaut (which is what it is when it is working) to xdebug (C:\xampp\php\php.exe).

I didn't change it.  I was just editing a file to make a change the book suggested when this changed and the darn thing quit working.  I am not quite sure how to change the PHP executable preferences back to the working value or prevent this from happening again.

Comment: More info: When it is not working and I go to the Run Configurations page, I see a red ball with an x in it and the message "The PHP file does not exist".  However if I go to the location that the PHP Executable is pointing to (see above) I can see that the php.exe file is there.

Comment: I have a work around.  I just simply created a new work space, copied the source files to the new workspace and created a new run configuration.  Works fine.  I would like any ideas on how I might have corrupted my old workspace though????

Comment: More interesting facts.  The problem came back when I added the following code snippet:                    <pre>
                <?php if($_POST) {print_r($_POST);?>
                </pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I have a fix.  It is weird, but it does work.  First some back ground that I left out above (written before I fully understood the problem):

The problem reappeared and actually I think it happened the first time after I added the following code snippet to the wrong location:

```
            <pre>
            <?php if($_POST) {print_r($_POST);?>
            </pre>
```

This was added to the following code (copied from PHP Solutions by David Powers) to the location BEFORE the

```
        </from>
```

tag instead of after it:

```
    <?php include('./includes/title.inc.php'); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8">
    <title>Japan Journey<?php echo "&#8212;{$title}"; ?></title>
    <link href="styles/journey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Japan Journey</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <?php include('./includes/menu.inc.php'); ?>
    <div id="maincontent">
    <h2>Contact Us </h2>
     <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation consectetur adipisicing
      elit.       Velit esse cillum dolore ullamco laboris nisi in reprehenderit in 
      voluptate. Mollit anim id est laborum. Sunt in culpa duis aute irure dolor   
      excepteur sint occaecat.</p>
      <form id="feedback" method="post" action="">
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="formbox">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="formbox">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="send" id="send" type="submit" value="Send message">

    </form> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

This caused the Run Configuration to change from a PHP Web Page to a PHP Script.  Ellipse then couldn't find the fictitious script.

The solution to this problem is as follows:

1) Fix the code
2) go into  RUN->Run Configurations
3) Delete the spurious configurations under PHP Script and reselect the correct configuration.
4) turn Auto generate on or off and then press apply and then do it again to bring it back to the original configuration.

The problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Time for necroposting :)

I also had this error about "Script cannot be found". In my case I just opened a separate PHP file, tried to debug it and got this error message. Managed to get rid of it by creating a workspace (project) for this file. Once workspace is created it defines URL for the project and relative path for the file in this project.

Fixed.